# My CSS Hover and Active styling is not working

Tags: html, css

Here is my navigation bar as follows:

```
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>  
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>  
   </ul>
  </nav>
```

And my CSS:

```
a: hover {

color: brown;

}

a: active {

color: #1490A5;
}
```

Im trying to have the active link in one colour and when I hover over it into another colour, its not working unfortunately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space between the two dots and the pseudo class

```
a:hover {

   color: brown;

}

a:active {

   color: #1490A5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove gap between `selector` and `pesudo`:

```
a: hover {
  ^----------------Remove

a: active
  ^---------------Remove
```

```css
a:hover {
color: brown;
}

a:active {
color: #1490A5;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
    <li><a href="resources.html">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>  
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space in the css elements, before :active and :hover,  your code should be like this :

```
a:hover {
 color: brown;
}

a:active {
   color: #1490A5;
}
```